# Does the SocketScan API support discovery/pairing on iOS?

Tags: ios, socketscan

Using either the iOS SDK or SocketScan API would be fine for accomplishing the task of pairing a scanner.

Does the Socket CHS 8ci support discovery from iOS?

Comment: Do you mean "can my app initiate the pairing with the scanner?" No, the user must go to the built-in Bluetooth settings page on iOS to pair a device. I don't think iOS even provides an API for listing discoverable devices (but I could be wrong)

Comment: Thanks.  I wanted to mimic the automatic pairing that the fitbit watch does.  It actually pairs the watch from within their application.  I've been trying to accomplish the task using iOS Core Bluetooth but it seems to sporadically even discover any devices.   Core Bluetooth does provide  - (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central
 didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
     advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData
                  RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI